# Firefox not support angular orientationchange event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, dom-events, orientation-changes

I have a problem with `orientationchange` in FireFox... in Chrome I don't event have, the event is triggered but in FireFox it's not called. This is the code:

```
angular.element($window).on('orientationchange', function () { ... });
```

I have the same problem with:

```
angular.element($window).bind('orientationchange', function () { ... });
```

and native JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () { ... });
```

I can't use jQuery... any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this solution and it's well supported:

```
        $window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").addListener(function(m) {
            // do something
        });
```